# struts2 set <run-as> in web.xml

Tags: struts2, weblogic, web.xml, servlet-filters, runas

So I am trying to migrate from struts1 to struts2 and the project have  in servlet

struts1 web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.servlet.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    ...
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    ...
    <run-as>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </run-as>
</servlet>
```

But in struts2 we use filter and I am not able to use < run-as>

```
<filter> ... </filter>
```

The < run-as> is link to the weblogic.xml and ejb

Can I use servlet in web.xml just for that? If yes, how can I do it?
Or Can I use ejb-ref in web.xml instead?

I am not sure what to do to with this.

Comment: Why do you need ran-as on Struts2 filter?